# retrieve ssh passphrase in macOS >= 10.13

Tags: macos, shell, go, keychain

This is working in `macOS < 10.13` via command line:

```
$ security find-generic-password -s "SSH" -a "/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Or using this [go](https://golang.org/) snippet (using https://github.com/keybase/go-keychain):

```
usr, _ := user.Current()
dir := usr.HomeDir
keyPath, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Join(dir, ".ssh/id_rsa"))
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
keyPassword, err := GetGenericPassword("SSH", keyPath, "", "")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("keyPassword = %s\n", keyPassword)
```

In macOS High Sierra this has been changed, doesn't work via command line also can't make it to work trying this:

```
keyPassword, err := keychain.GetGenericPassword("OpenSSH", keyPath, "SSH: "+keyPath, "com.apple.ssh.passphrases")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("keyPassword = %s\n", keyPassword)
```

I fund this post, could be related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268175/104123.

Any ideas if this is possible in latest macOs versions?